# How to use regex in Grav regex_replace() function in Twig template

Tags: regex, grav

Their example by the link https://learn.getgrav.org/17/themes/twig-tags-filters-functions/functions#regex-replace works.

But something like

```
{% set result = regex_replace('The quick brown fox', ['/(\s)?/'], ['']) %}
{{ result }}
```

does not work - the string is not changed

How to use regex in their wrapper?

Comment: Please accept the answers that solves your issue/question, or which was most helpful in finding a solution to the question/issue. This helps future readers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Sorry I've overlooked the link in your question.

Try to escape the backslash. See [this issue](https://github.com/getgrav/grav/issues/833#issuecomment-218992612) on regex_replace.

The following works fine:

```
{% set result = regex_replace('The quick brown fox', ['/(\\s)?/'], ['']) %}
{{ result }}
```

Result: Thequickbrownfox

Btw: The parenthesis and question mark are not necessary in your example.

**Original:**

Grav adds a custom filter for this. See https://learn.getgrav.org/17/themes/twig-tags-filters-functions/filters#regex-replace.

It's a wrapper around PHP's `preg_replace()`.

Example:

```
'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.' | regex_replace(['/quick/','/brown/','/fox/','/dog/'], ['slow','black','bear','turtle'])
```

which yields:

```
The slow black bear jumps over the lazy turtle.
```

Comment: It should be `\\s` instead of `\s`. Now it works